# Visual Studio Code - customize color of specific html tags

Tags: visual-studio-code

After searching high and low, I don't seem to able to find out how to customize the color of specific html tags in Visual Studio Code. Changing the color of them all is easy enough, with the following textmate scope:

***entity.name.tag.html***

That changes all tags. But what if you want to change just the color of the "Form" tag? i.e.`<form></form>`
So how do I make the "Form" tag distinct in color from the "Div" tags, for instance?

Inspecting the editor tokens/scope within VSC, I can see scopes such as:

***meta.tag.structure.form.start.html***

But that changes something else, not the Form tag itself.

Comment: use the extension `Highlight`

Comment: Works well, thank you! Here's the full url: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fabiospampinato.vscode-highlight

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why  isn't working for you?  This works for me:

```
  "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "textMateRules": [
      {
        "scope": "meta.tag.structure.form.start.html entity.name.tag, meta.tag.structure.form.end.html entity.name.tag",
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#00ff00",
          "fontStyle": "bold"
        }
      },
    ]
  },
```

Note that I have to add `entity.name.tag` to each scope selector to get it to work.  Demo:

[image: html form color change]

Was there something else you were trying to accomplish?

Comment: That works also, thanks. Adding "entity.name.tag" was the important missing bit. That is all I need to accomplish.